# Ranked returns in R

Tags: r, return, match, rank

```
returns <- data.frame(date = c('2015.01.01','2015.01.02','2015.01.03','2015.01.04'),
                  Asset1 = as.numeric(c('0.1','0.1','0.1','0.1')),
                  Asset2 = as.numeric(c('0.2','0.2','0.2','0.2')),
                  Asset3 = as.numeric(c('0.3','0.3','0.3','0.3')))

Rank <- data.frame(date = c('2015.01.01','2015.01.02','2015.01.03','2015.01.04'),
                  Asset1 = as.numeric(c('3','3','3','3')),
                  Asset2 = as.numeric(c('1','1','1','1')),
                  Asset3 = as.numeric(c('2','2','2','2')))
```

I would like to match rank 1 returns to column 1 in new data frame. Numbers and Ranks can change quite a bit so just moving column around won't work. I think my English didn't come out too clear in first post. Result should look like this.

```
Result <- data.frame(date = c('2015.01.01','2015.01.02','2015.01.03','2015.01.04'),
                         Rank1 = as.numeric(c('0.2','0.2','0.2','0.2')),
                         Rank2 = as.numeric(c('0.3','0.3','0.3','0.3')),
                         Rank3 = as.numeric(c('0.1','0.1','0.1','0.1')))
```

As best ranked (for example sake) is asset 2, so column Rank1 will always get Asset2 return. Rank2 will get Asset3 return as it is ranked 2 for whole time. These can change in real world, so would appreciate taking that account.

Here is original answer, thanks for that, but it will mix up Result. Don't know what it is doing actually.

```
Result1 <- returns
Result1[-1] <- returns[-1][cbind(1:nrow(Rank),as.numeric(t(Rank[-1])))]
```

Comment: Why do you use characters instead of numerics?

Comment: I think the 'Result' have some values not corresponding to that in the Rank

Comment: I tried to be accurate as I can, can't find error in Result.

Comment: I'm very beginner in R and did this to show you the problem. Should have turn them to numerics for sure. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Let me check the code again.  Thanks for getting back.

Comment: I think in the second row, there is some mix up in the Result dataset?  If the Rank is 3 1 2 , 0.045 should come first

Comment: Sry that I changed the data, maybe that was the problem. Returns are what they are. Now I would only like to match 1 Ranked asset with that assets return, whatever it is to Results first column.

Comment: Changed the code, check it now

Comment: Ok, will try to get that working on my full sample. At least works for that. Takes some time, so I understand what it is doing. Many thanks for taking time for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `row/column` indexing. We `order` the 'Rank' numeric columns by row ('ri'), use that as 'column' index, `cbind` with `row` index (`1:nrow(Rank)`), extract the elements from 'returns' dataset and assign it to the 'Result1' we created earlier to keep the same structure.

```
 Result1 <- returns
 ri <- c(t(apply(Rank[-1], 1, order)))
 Result1[-1] <- returns[-1][cbind(1:nrow(Rank), ri)]
 names(Result1) <- sub('_.*', '', names(Result1))
 identical(Result1, Result)
 #[1] TRUE
```

Comment: RankedR <- function(x,y){
Result1 <- x
Result1[-1] <- x[-1][cbind(1:nrow(y),as.numeric(t(y[-1])))]
return(as.data.frame(Result1))
}

Comment: Thats my first function in R, thanks. It gives me correct values, but is that best/nicest way to write functions?

Comment: Edited question for my bad english, but seems like your code is some how mixing the result. First it looked ok, but when I tested it to this very straight forward example, something went wrong. Might be that this is too simple some how and I can't explain it correctly. Goal is to get data frame where 1 column is best ranked assets return and so on. In excel have done this with IF functions, but can't find anything to relate to in R